# Conference claims they have indexed proceedings and publisher denies it

Tags: journals, conference, disreputable-publishers, springer, proceedings

There is a conference which says that the proceedings will by published in Springer. Normally, Springer conferences mention the series of the volume that the proceedings will be published (LNCS, CCIS or LNBIP). This one doesn't mention any thing, all  they're writing is "Approved by Springer". When I emailed the organizer of the conference, he said the the series are LNCS. So I thought I should I check the official conference list by Springer, but I didn't find the conference. I wrote an email to Springer and they said that the conference has not been accepted for the LNCS series.

One of the main things why I considered this conference is that they're have a best paper session where 2 papers will get an invitation to send an extended version to another journal (Also in Springer). But I am not sure if that's also true now that I know the organizer wasn't honest about the series of the conference. I also think that my supervisor will ask me to submit anyways. I don't know what to do.

PS: It's really sad, that anyone can use a publisher name just like that. Does the publisher can't really do anything about that ?

Comment: How is an invitation to submit a paper to a journal supposed to be an award? You can submit your papers to whichever journal you want. Whether they will publish it is a different question. Or do they claim the conference presentation replaces the peer review? Either way it looks very shady.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a lot of predatory journals, and some of them organize conferences. Some of these organize conferences with information that is outright false, in order to get money from academic in exchange of "academic credit" i.e. publications. Stay very away from these organizations, as most reputable academic institution would see worse having a publication in these places than no publications at all.

Can Springer do something about it? I assume their lawyers are on it, but its the same for any institution that is based on scamming. Its hard to get rid of them because they are playing outside the law already.

Comment: Extending on this answer, I hope for the author that they havn't signed anything yet that would grant the publication permission to the conference organizers. In this case, they should withdraw the paper and submit somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is, if they lied about the conference proceedings. Then, there is no publication at all. There also the possibility that will actually have a proceedings but they will submit it elsewhere.

Comment: @U.User indeed, often they will still publish them in some journal with a bland name like "journal of international scientific research". You don't want to risk giving them permission to publish